Add bool to u8 in rust correctly
I am currently working on a CPU emulator in Rust and want to make sure I am following best practices for my code (or as close to best as I can get). I'm implementing the ADDC() function which is add with carry flag.
Currently my flags register is 4 bools in a row as a struct found below.
struct FlagsRegister {
    zero: bool,
    subtract: bool,
    half_carry: bool,
    carry: bool,
}

This is then converted to and from 8bit bools into a single 8bit number as per the specifications.
My current ADDC code is:
fn addc(&mut self, value: u8) -> u8 {
        let (new_value, did_overflow) = self.registers.a.overflowing_add(value + self.registers.f.carry);
        self.registers.f.zero = new_value == 0;
        self.registers.f.subtract = false;
        self.registers.f.carry = did_overflow;
        self.registers.f.half_carry = (self.registers.a & 0xF) + (value & 0xF) > 0xF;
        new_value
    }

The keyline is the first one with the let value as the rest are just flag operations. It gives the error can't add bool to u8 though. What is the correct way in rust to pull the actual numerical value from the bool?
Would it be mem::transmute? or something else?

soo just as u8?

wait am I just being stupid and forgetting about as u8...

I am honestly a muppet, it was just to use
as u8.
Thanks KamilCuk
